# Unable to find logs for users access to credentials for the Key Vault

Tags: azure-keyvault

I am exploring this Key Vault to be used as a credentials store (something like 1Password for Teams).

I am having trouble finding the place to see who added/updated/deleted credentials. I can only find the audit log for managing the vault itself.

Are there something else to configure for enable this logging (if it's not on by default)? Chat support does not have any idea as well.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can enable the `AuditEvent` in the `Diagnostic settings` of your keyvault.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/logging

I set it to send logs to my storage account, then I can check the logs in the container named `insights-logs-auditevent`(about half an hour delay of the container creation), to see who do the operations, just check the `identity` in each log.

For example, I want to see who created a secret, then I can find a log like below(hid the sensitive information).

```
{
   "time":"2020-04-28T06:56:04.1406420Z",
   "category":"AuditEvent",
   "operationName":"SecretSet",
   "resultType":"Success",
   "correlationId":"xxxxx",
   "callerIpAddress":"xxxxxx",
   "identity":{
      "claim":{
         "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier":"15xxxxx81d65",
         "appid":"36xxxxx1efe",
         "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope":"user_impersonation",
         "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn":"xxxxx@microsoft.com",
         "ipaddr":"xxxxxxx",
         "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences":"pwd"
      }
   },
   "properties":{
      "id":"https://joykeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/sec789",
      "clientInfo":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36 Edg/81.0.416.64",
      "subnetId":"(unknown)",
      "httpStatusCode":200,
      "requestUri":"https://joykeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/sec789?api-version=7.0",
      "isAccessPolicyMatch":true,
      "secretProperties":{
         "attributes":{
            "enabled":true
         }
      }
   },
   "resourceId":"/SUBSCRIPTIONS/xxxx/RESOURCEGROUPS/xxxxx/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.KEYVAULT/VAULTS/JOYKEYVAULT",
   "operationVersion":"7.0",
   "resultSignature":"OK",
   "durationMs":"80"
}
```

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/logging#interpret), the `operationName` of `Create a secret` is `SecretSet`, from the `identity`, we can see the user `xxxxx@microsoft.com` created it, from the `properties`, we can see the user created the secret `sec789`.

Comment: Thanks! I manage to link all the stuffs and enabled all logging but I'm still not sure how to pull that info out from the Query Editor. It's pretty complicated from what I see in Monitoring -> Logs. I am using the Web UI, not PowerShell.

Comment: @CyberMew I just download the log from the storage to local. Anyway I think it answers your question, could you accept it? :-)